# PHP preg_match() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given Error

Tags: php

this error is really confusing me. -

Warning: preg_match() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/s1lentec/public_html/restricted/registration-process.php on line 98

Here is the code for it -

```
if (isset($_POST["zipCode"]) && $_POST["zipCode"] != "") {
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\-]$/")) {
        if (strlen($_POST["zipCode"] != 5) || strlen($_POST["zipCode"] != 9) || strlen($_POST["zipCode"] != 10)) {
            $_SESSION["error"][] = "ZIP code is not valid.  Valid format is xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx";
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is the next bit of code is almost exactly the same and it throws no error -

```
if (isset($_POST["phoneNumber"]) && $_POST["phoneNumber"] != "") {
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\-]$/")) {
        if (strlen($_POST["phoneNumber"] != 7) || strlen($_POST["phoneNumber"] != 8) || strlen($_POST["phoneNumber"] != 10) || strlen($_POST["phoneNumber"] != 12)) {
            $_SESSION["error"][] = "Phone number is not valid.  Valid format is xxx-xxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx";
        }
    }
}
```

I even copy/pasted the latter into the formers place and it still throws the same error.  Even their database properties are the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I already fixed the other bugs and have tried reducing/isolating this bug to but I just cannot figure it out.  :/

Comment: Read the message. `preg_match()` expects _two_ parameters, but you're only passing _one_. I don't see how it could be any clearer. Take a look at the manual [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Obviously I understand that, but why is expecting two parameters?  especially when the next bit of code is almost exactly the same and yet throws no error when given an almost exact same input?

Comment: Clearly you don't understand it or you wouldn't be here. Ask yourself how PHP knows what to apply your regular expression to. Then read the reference I linked to and it should all become obvious.

Comment: Is the second preg_match being executed: it won't show an error unless $_POST['phoneNumber'] actually contains a value

Answer (score 0):

Preg_match expects two paramaters, variable you are checking and regex. So in this case it should be like: 
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9-]$/", $_POST['zipCode']))

Comment: My bad, I noticed it immediately after posting, but I'm on mobile so edit took longer time. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks user3560463.  That was glaringly obvious and I feel like a moron for missing it but the fact that the phoneNumber code wasn't throwing the exact same error threw me off.  Much appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The function, like others have said requires 2 parameters, and you only passed one.

But for the reason why one of the blocks shows an error and the other doesn't, is because PHP only throws errors in code that gets run. If you have code inside an `if` statement that never happens, the code inside that `if` statement, even if wrong, won't throw an error.

In the case above, you probably have the `phoneNumber` variable not being sent / set, so the `preg_match` function is never running.

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Also, to clean up your code a little bit, instead of having to run both `isset()` and check if the variable is empty, you can use the function `empty()`.

`if(isset($_POST["phoneNumber"]) && $_POST["phoneNumber"] != "") { }`

turns into

`if(!empty($_POST['phoneNumber'])) { }`

The PHP reference for `preg_match` can be found at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)